# Не понятен синтаксис добавленного аргумента в lapply()

Tags: r

Всем привет!
Нужна помощь в понимании одного упражнения на Datacamp.
[image: Задача]
[image: Ответ]

Не ясна часть кода:

```
tables <- lapply(table_names, dbReadTable, conn = con)
```

Зачем здесь нужен `conn = con`?

Comment: У вас же написано: *Connect to the MySQL database: con*. Это объект подключения к базе данных, откуда будут считаны данные для заполнения таблицы. `conn` - это именной аргумент (не позиционный).

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, но все равно не ясно. В спеке написано, что в функции lapply() на первом месте стоит массив данных(tables_names, это ясно), на другом функция обраьатывающая каждый элемент из tables_names, а какие аргументы стоят дальше - неясно. Какую задачу выполняет выражение conn = con?

Comment: т.е, для каждого элемента массива нужно будет создать переменную conn...и что дальше? Обьясните плиз

Comment: Там `...`, т.е. после могут следовать именные аргументы в любом порядке. Никаких переменных conn не создаёт, это лишь ещё один аргумент, переданный в lapply.

Comment: Хорошо, вы правы Виктор, т.к я удалил выражение conn = con и код исполняется с тем же результатом. Но вопрос, зачем же оно нужно было конкретно в этом примере, остается висеть в воздухе))

Answer (score 0):

Вы верно нашли ошибку в задании.
Синтаксис "лапли" подразумевает первый аргумент - элемент подлежащий обработке. В данном случае это:
table_names, он уже содержит в себе установленный коннект с БД ( dbListTables(con) ).
Второй аргумент lapply подразумевает функцию, которая будет применена ко всем элементам, входящим в первый аргумент  ( dbListTables(con) ).
То есть коннект уже был установлен, когда запрашивался список таблиц в базе.
Если вы уберете оба "con" из lapply, функция lapply объявит забастовку.

Кст. дальше должно быть 
dbDisconnect(con)

иначе база начнет подтормаживать от множества открытых сессий.

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DBI/versions/0.5-1/topics/dbReadTable